# MySQL date and datetime formats unrecognised by Data Studio

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, looker-studio

I've linked Google data studio with a MySQL database using the standard connector. Almost everything works fine except for ***date*** and ***datetime*** fields.

I have these 2 fields in phpmyadmin (field name, ***field type***, `output`):

- Validated_date ***datetime*** `2017-09-27 12:31:04`
- Expiration_date ***date*** `2017-12-24`

In Data Studio I've set these types, but none of them are recognised:

- Validated_date  ***Date Hour (YYYYMMDDHH)***
- Expiration_date ***Date (YYYYMMDD)***

I tried to format the field with date_format in my SELECT:

```
DATE_FORMAT(p.Expiration_date, '%Y%m%d') AS "Expiration Date"
```

I even tried other date_formats but they're never recognised as dates in Data Studio:

```
DATE_FORMAT(p.Expiration_date, '%Y/%m/%d') AS "Expiration Date"
DATE_FORMAT(p.Expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS "Expiration Date"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue. My approach to solve this is to modify the date format within Google Data Studio by creating a new dimension, reformatting the mySQL Datetime into the desired format.

In your example you use DATE_FORMAT. I wonder if you apply this in Data Studio (which does not know DATE_FORMAT) or in mySQL?. If you do it in data studio and leave your mySQL/phpmyadmin untouched you can use this:

```
TODATE(your-date-field, 'DEFAULT_DASH', '%Y%m%d')
```

This will take the date format YYYY-MM-DD with optional time in HH:ii:ss and reformat it into YYYYMMDD which works with data studio.

Comment: That should be explained in Google's date format help, worked perfectly, upvoted.

Comment: pretty disappointing that data studion still doesn't support cloud sql timestamp and datetime objects without this explicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried directly with Data Studio but when I extract datetime fields from mySQL to use in BigQuery I use:

> CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), [DATETIME_FIELD])

This removed any milliseconds which generally cause problems and convert it to a recognisable datetime format for Google

Answer (score 0):

I have used the follow formule and working for me:

```
TODATE(yor-field-from-mysql, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Then I choose ***YYYYMMDDhhmm*** format in DataStudio. I hope it helps.

***Edit***: In this case, date came from javascript using moment.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, the only solution was create a formula this way:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(field, 1, 4), SUBSTR(field, 6, 2), SUBSTR(field, 9, 2))
```

and use this as AAAAMMDD format