# Can't sort bar chart by transformed mysql timestamp in Google Data Studio

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, bar-chart, looker-studio

I've linked Google data studio with a MySQL database using the standard connector. Everything works except sorting correctly by date.

Database columns configured like this:

- **price** decimal(15,2) not null `24.59`
- **last_changed** timestamp not null `2019-03-25 19:24:52`

GDS datasource fields configured (as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365683/mysql-date-and-datetime-formats-unrecognised-by-data-studio)) like this:

- **last_changed** Date(YYYYMMDD) `2019-03-25`
- **sold_at** GDS function `TODATE(last_changed, 'DEFAULT_DASH', '%Y%m%d')`

GDS bar chart configured like this:

- **time dimension** sold_at **as date**
- **dimension** sold_at **as date**
- **value metric** price **as sum**
- **sorting** sold_at **as date ascending**
- **time range** auto **from** date picker with **default** set to **current month**

***I am experiencing the following issue:*** When **sorting** is set to **sold_at** the bar chart is empty with the default date range. Only when i go back at least one month it displays values in the chart but also cuts off the last day so that its less than it should be. Only when **sorting** is set to **price** it displays everything correctly, even in the current month. Also when switching from **sorting** set to **price** to **sold_at** while the default time range is selected it shows the **sold_at** field under *Invalid* in the sorting modal.

I tried modifying the database column to datetime instead of timestamp but it didnt change anything. I also tried setting a different default time range but that doesnt change anything also. It keeps showing no data for 1 month back.

Any idea or someone who already stumbled across this scenario?

Comment: look into the mysql logs to see what actually is send to the database there you also can see what happens when you change the settings.

Comment: @nbk Yeah, i've had the same idea just before you commented. Seems like GDS sets the select limit to 100,000 entries so im missing about 7000 and thats why im seeing these issues. Do you have any idea on how to prevent GDS from doing that?

Comment: @nbk solved, thanks for the tip nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that come across the same issue:

This issue was caused by the MYSQL timestamp/datetime column having optional Hrs:Min:Sec. This caused the GDS mysql query to not be able to group them by day and thus resulting in more than 100000 rows, which is more than the hardcoded limit set by the connector.

Solution: Added another timestamp/datetime column and filled it with

`UPDATE table SET newcolumn = DATE_FORMAT(oldcolumn, '%Y/%m/%d');`

It now works like a charm.